# How to ping/connect to a KVM on another machine in the same lan?

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have 2 machines in my cluster, say `M1` and `M2`. I have one machine installed with a VM (brought up by `virt-install`), say `VM` on `M2`.

My `M2` can ping the IP address of `VM`. My `M1` and `M2` can also ping each other.

But `M1` cannot reach out to `VM`. What additional setup do I need to let `M1` able to talk to `VM`? Like bridges or routers?

Thanks in advance!